# How to lookup an integer in an N sized list in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, list, constant-time

Properties of the list:

1. must be of size N, where N is the amount of integers
2. no empty cells
3. numbers may not be perfectly sequential (i.e. {-23,-15,-3,1,2,6,7,8,15,100})
4. Insertion/Lookup needs to be in constant time.

My first instinct was to use a hash table, but this would create unused cells where numbers are skipped.

Is there any way such a list can be constructed to check in constant time if a number exists in that list?

Comment: Can you use a vector of elements such that `V[i+k] = j`, such that `L[j]=i`, where k is some starting offset and V and L are your vector and list respectively? This seems like cheating since it essentially gets around requirement 2 on a technicality.

Comment: do you need to retain the order? A `Set` would work if you don't need the order. Even then you could go with something similar to Java's `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: Codie:  The vector idea sounds plausible, would require further investigation.
Mateusz:  I forgot to say that insertion and lookup needs to be in constant time, but log n insertion isn't so bad, it may be my best bet at this point.

Comment: @OneEyed well `LinkedHashSet` is supposed to provide constant time insertion, lookup and removal. Not sure are you looking for a platform specific solution but you can check if that platform has an equivalent data structure or just check Java's source code and implement it yourself

Comment: "No wasted space" is an extremely ill-posed constraint. Also, how are we supposed to have any room for, say, the size field? It's just about impossible to get the size down to 0 for an empty data structure.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I believe you have the answer.  Please post, and I'll accept it.  Thanks.  It could be in any programming language.

Comment: A hashtable lookup isn't O(1) time, it's O(1) comparisons. A hash needs at least log_2(N) bits, so a lookup can't be faster than O(log N).

Comment: @Anonymous isn't number comparison considered O(1)? In this case your hashcode is just the number, you don't need to compute it and comparing hashcodes is just comparing 2 numbers.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk But then the runtime depends on the inputs (for example, if the input is all multiples of the size of the hash table). To get O(1) worst-case average lookup comparisons, you need universal hashing and not just hash(N)=N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments, you can go with a `Set`, depending on your exact use case you can check out things like Java's [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you need to maintain the order which according to the doc is supposed to be constant time:

> Like HashSet, it provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (add, contains and remove), assuming the hash function
>   disperses elements properly among the buckets.

If you are looking for solutions on other platforms maybe there are equivalent implementations or you can check Java's source code and implement it yourself.

Comment: Hash tables has complexity O(1) looking at amortized time, but not when looking single operation. In worst cases Hash table has O(N) .

Comment: @LukaRahne could you expand? Hash tables have a worst case O(n) complexity should conflicts occur, true, but I do not see how it would be O(N^2)? It's not really amortized time, it's just that when you get a lot of conflicts you degrade each bucket to a list or you need to rehash the entry N times. Furthemore we are talking about numbers here so this does not really apply even if we have duplicates because we will not have multiple entries with the same hashcode.

Comment: I made mistake about O(N^2). Contrary one can construct such set of operations that making N (insert/delete/lookup) operations will result in O(N^2) time.

Comment: @LukaRahne that's only if you have hash collisions and can have duplicates. Here we are operating on numbers so we won't have multiple values for the same hash code.

Comment: In this case if you use integers on moderen system you need to allocate 64 * 2^64 bits of memory, to sore arbitrary 64bit number without collision.

Comment: @LukaRahne we dont care about duplicates since those are numbers, they will be just overriden and not linked/rehashed you dont need to allocate that much memory

Comment: I don't think you can get FIFO semantics with LinkedHashSet though.